# Jprofiler heap walker taking too long to take snapshot and take too long in disconnecting the session

Tags: java, testing, google-kubernetes-engine, jprofiler

I have installed `Jprofiler` latest version 14.0 for some project requirements. I attach  it to running JVM in `kubernetes` cluster present on another computer through direct SSH connection . The jprofiler successfully attaches and run on container present there.
But as I  visit `Heap walker` in `jprofiler` for taking the `snapshot` of current heap memory usage. It successfully loaded the heap dump but
it got stuck while calculating the heap size allocations to different objects and take too long still unable to calculate it.
[image]

2. while we disconnect the running session to exit it also take long time. Why does it
   [image]
3. HPROF Snapshot
   [image]

4./TMP/Jprofiler_Error.log Screen Shot
[image]

How does these both problems can be solved?

As detailed above I want help in  resolving issue in `jprofiler` `heap walker`. why it is taking too long in taking snapshot?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow, please leave codes, and if not at least, direct images instead of image links to the question, check this: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask#:~:text=How%20do%20I%20ask%20a%20good%20question%3F%201,Respond%20to%20feedback%20after%20posting%20...%20More%20items)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Is there any output in $TMP/jprofiler_error.log? Can you take an HPROF snapshot instead of using the heap walker? This is an option in the connection dialog.

Comment: @IngoKegel  Can you please tell the location of  $TMP/jprofiler_error.log  file ? And also get stuck in HPROF snapshot. I have attached image above of it.

Comment: @IngoKegel I have attached Above ScreenShot of   $TMP/jprofiler_error.log file .Please look into that.